# Three .json files 'StockChart' - highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Please help by taking StockChart. Pinning three `.json` files as in the example , But does not work. The code is below:

[www.jsfiddle.net/d8xwjxg7/2](http://www.jsfiddle.net/d8xwjxg7/2/)

Comment: I see no json files. What 3 json files?

Comment: Look:
 names = ['SummaryTempGorycz', 'SummaryTempMorskie', 'SummaryTempPiecStawow'],
            // create the chart when all data is loaded
$.getJSON('http://www.iklimat.pl/'+names()+'.php', function (data) {}

Comment: Odd, when I went to your js fiddle those items were not there.

Comment: from the table "names" form a 3 json files replacing the url in $.getJSON

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code:

`$.getJSON('http://www.iklimat.pl/'+name()+'.php', function (data) {`

Should be:

`$.getJSON('http://www.iklimat.pl/'+ name +'.php', function (data) {`

Since `name` is a string not a function.

Also, this will not work in a JSFiddle since you cannot load files not from the site the javascript is running on without the endpoint you are accessing setting the `access-allow-control-origin` header.

EDIT:

I have sorted out the issue you were having getting data, however there is an issue with that data.
http://jsfiddle.net/d8xwjxg7/5/

Comment: I use 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: There is an issue with the data you are pulling back, check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8xwjxg7/5/

Comment: Console: Highcharts error nr 13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Comment: Yes, check out what Highcharts is saying: http://jsfiddle.net/d8xwjxg7/6/

http://www.highcharts.com/errors/12

Comment: Could you paste your data?